# Custom shortcodes not inserting into visual composer columns

Tags: functions, shortcode

I have made an custom single image shortcode for visual composer.I created a row and 6 column in visual composer and tried to insert my custom shortcode into a column but it prepends to the column

here is my custom shortcode

```
/**
* as seen on Shortcode
*/

function as_seen_on_section_short( $atts ){

    $featuredLogo = shortcode_atts( array(

        'logo'   =>  ''

        ),$atts ); ?>


        <!-- as seen on section starts-->
        <div class="as-seen-on">
            <?php
                $logo_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($featuredLogo['logo']);
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $logo_img[0];?>" alt="published-img" class="img-responsive" width="80">
        </div>
        <!-- as seen on section ends -->


<?php
}

add_shortcode('published_featured','as_seen_on_section_short');


/**
* visual composer map
**/



function featured_section_element_vc(){

    vc_map( array(

        'name'   =>  __( 'Featured Section','published' ),
        'base'   =>  'published_featured',
        'params'  =>  array(


                array(

                    'param_name'  =>  'logo',
                    'type'        =>  'attach_image',
                    'heading'     =>  'Logo',

                    ),

            )

        ) );

}

add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'featured_section_element_vc' );
```

and here is the output from visual composer from my console

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">       
  <div class="as-seen-on">
    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress3/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/2-150x150.jpg" alt="published-img" class="img-responsive" width="80">
        </div>            
    <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-2">
      <div class="vc_column-inner ">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

the 'as-seen-on' class supposed to be within the 'wpb-wrapper' class.visual composer's own shortcodes seems to be working fine within a column.

Comment: Have a look at the shortcode examples in WordPress codex, or search for shortcode output questions on this site. Shortcodes should return output, not output content directly.